# Not able to get attribute value using component.get in init method

Tags: aura-attribute

I am setting a attribute value in helper using component.set("v.value",result( and calling this helper in init handler to show/hide some values depending on this boolean value. But when I try to access this value that i had set in helper in Init handler I am not getting the correct value which was returned from server.

Here is my helper method code:

```
getAccessCheck : function(component) {
 var actionCheckccess = component.get("c.chkaccess”);

    actionCheckccess.setParams({
        "recordId": component.get("v.recordId")
    });

    actionCheckccess.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
         result= response.getReturnValue();
        if(state === "SUCCESS") {
            if(result){
                component.set("v.isCanada", result);//Getting true from server and setting to an attribute
                console.log('result'+result);//getting true here also
            }
        }
        else {
      console.log('Error has occurred in  access check');
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(actionCheckccess);
```

}

I am calling this helper in Init Handler like this:

```
doInit : function(component) {

helper.getAccessCheck(component)
```

when i try to access this value of attribute that was set in helper still i always get false when in fact the value returned from server is true and that is getting set in helper.

```
component.get("v.isCanada"); // I am getting false here
console.log(component.get("v.isCanada")) // I am getting false here
```

}

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mixed up synchronous and asynchronous code here. Your Apex server call runs asynchronously:

```
$A.enqueueAction(actionCheckccess);
```

so your code in `doInit()` cannot access its value, because the asynchronous action hasn't yet completed and your callback hasn't executed.

Do the work you need to do in the callback function, not in `doInit()`. Or drop the obsolete Aura framework and switch to Lightning Web Components, where it's easy to use async/await to deal with these kinds of patterns.